# Probability of 81 flips having more heads than 80 flips, given arbitrary success rate

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose, person X and Y are both flipping coins with equal probability of heads, $p$ (not necessarily $0.5$. X flips her coin 80 coins, while Y flips his coin 81 times. Find the probability Y flips more heads than X.

This is similar to prior questions, but here, the probability of heads is $p$, and it holds for both people, so it didn't immediately make sense to me whether the answer here should be $0.5$ or $p$ (it is the latter, which I do not understand from previous threads about similar problems).

Comment: I think your title is incorrect for two reasons: 1) it's 81 rather than 80.  2) In the explanation, you say the question is the probability of X getting more heads than Y which means the probability of that the lesser number of flips get more heads. So, without these two differences,  I think there can be a lot of correct answers but people want to answer the correct question which is currently unclear.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither $1/2$ nor $p$ is the answer in general. If $r=\sum_{k=0}^{80} {80 \choose k}^2 p^{2k}(1-p)^{160-2k}$ is the chance the 80 tosses of X yield the same number of heads as the first 80 tosses of Y, then the  probability Y flips strictly more heads than X is $rp+(1-r)/2$.

Comment: Yuval: I like that approach but where does the $\frac{{(1-r)}{2}$ come from ? That looks like 1/2 of the probability of them having different numbers of heads after 80 flips But isn't there still one more flip remaining for Y that could matter for that case.

Comment: @markleeds 
If $Y$ is already leading after they both tossed 80 times, then $Y$ will still be leading after one more toss. And if $X$ is leading, then one more toss for $Y$ will not bring $Y$ into the lead.

Comment: aaaaah. very clever. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After tossing $80$ coins each, let $z$ be the $Pr$ that $Y$ is **ahead**.
By symmetry, $z$ is also the $Pr$ that $X$ is ahead, and P(tie)  $= 1-2z$.

$Y$ has just two ways to win:  either $Y$ is  ahead before the last toss,  or there is a tie and $Y$ then gets $H$.

Thus P($Y$ wins) $= z + (1-2z)\cdot p $